# C Function Pointer in a while loop

Tags: function, loops, pointers, while-loop

i'm trying to run all the functions in list_A through a function pointer in a while loop.
The console does not return me anything.

thanks for the help!

```
void func_A(){     printf("Hello A");}
void func_B(){     printf("Hello B");}
void func_C(){     printf("Hello C");}

typedef void (*list)(void);     

list list_A[] = { func_A,func_B,func_C, 0 };
list list_B[] = { func_A, 0 };

void func(list *list_p)
{
    while (*list_p++ != 0) 
    {
      (*list_p)();
    }
}

int main()
{
    func(list_A);
}
```

I was expecting the print of A, B, C, but for some reasons functions are nor really called

Comment: A `for()` loop might be easier to understand here:  `for ( ;*list_p; listp++ ) {(*list_p)()};`

Answer (score 1):

The segmentation error is thrown because the list pointer is incremented after the condition is checked but before the function pointer is called, thus you're trying to call the fourth element on the third iteration, which isn't a function, but an integer.

Try to increment it inside the loop after calling the function pointer and check if the current element is not null as a loop condition.

Comment: Yep, I did as you said and it works now, many thanks!

Comment: void func(list *list_p)
{
    while (*list_p!=0) 
    {
        (*list_p)();
      
        *list_p++;
    }
}